# The declared package "" does not match the expected package "(file name)"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Java and I'm using Visual Studio Code. When I run the code it works fine, but every program in java (even a basic Hello World program) gives me this error.

```
The declared package "" does not match the expected package "helloWorld"
```

I didn't find any solutions on internet and I don't know how to fix this.

here is the code:

```
public class helloworld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("hello world");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Code please or we can't know apart from guesswork

Comment: "*When I run the code it works fine, but every program in java (even a basic Hello World program) gives me this error.*" - What do you mean by "*When I run the code*" and "*every program in java*"? Either the program compiles (producing a `.class` file executable by the JVM) or not.

Comment: @DavideAntipa please [edit] the question and add the source code.

Comment: [Code compiles fine](https://ideone.com/rSHaOW). Please describe EXACTLY what you do that leads to the compilation error. My guess is that the `helloworld.java` class is  in a sub-directory `helloWorld` and that you try to compile the fine with a command similalr to this one: `javac helloWorld/helloworld.java`. If so, please `cd` in the `helloWorld`-directory and execute `javac` from there: `javavc helloworld.java`.

Comment: Best guess is that you created a folder named `helloWorld` and placed the `helloworld.java` source file inside that folder. In Java, folders are used to represent *packages*, so if you create your Java source files in folders, then you need a matching `package` statement in the source file. Add the following line to the *beginning* of your source file: `package helloWorld;`. Alternative: Move the source file out of the folder.

Comment: BTW: take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with uppercase character and be CamelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your compiler error and the code you showed, you have the following folder/package structure in the project you have created:

```
src
|
|-helloWorld
       |
       | helloworld.java
```

If that's the case, the "expected package" is the full package definition your java file is defined in, in this case, "helloWorld"

If you had this other folder structure:

```
src
|
|-helloWorld (folder/package)
       |
       | subfolder (subfolder/package)
                 |
                 | helloworld.java
```

then your expected package for the class helloworld would be helloWorld.subfolder

To actually define that package in the .java file, you must write the following as the first code line of the file (this is mandatory):

```
package fullpackage;
```

In your example, this would be:

```
package helloWorld;
```

The full code example as I can see it, would be for you something like...

```
package helloWorld;
public class helloworld {
   // the rest of your main method and code here
}
```

Comment: "*I'm going to do a wild guess...*" - We should not post speculative answers. We should  rather ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: I'll rephrase that to avoid being poetic and be explicit about the reasons for the answer

Comment: The solution works, I have that folder structure, thanks. Sorry for being not very specific

Comment: Package names should be lowercase by conventions.